# TFS 2010 access, for INTERNET only specific users

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access

How can i achieve this goal?
my company have developers in outside the company.
they want access to TFS via internet
how can i achieve this goal?

1 - as i want (tfs 2010) will Show to them .
or 
2 - show to internet for our specific users. as same as the (TFS WEB ACCESS) but it is only for intranet or locally.

sorry for my English , new learners!

Comment: Are the outside developers working from home or are they in a remote office? Do they only require TFS Web Access or do they need to be able to connect to TFS using Team Explorer so they can check in code?

Comment: they are using from different countries like nigeria germqany etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to speak to your companies network administrators and ask them what an acceptable solution is based on their security requirements.

1. Use a VPN, very simple if your infrastructure already supports using VPNs
2. Configure your network to allow external requests to be routed to your TFS server

Before you speak to the network Admins, read [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668967.aspx) as it explains a number of connection scenarios.

Comment: i have checked that document not helping me....as im beggineers